# For each line, create a new line to append with mutliple entries from another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Ok im back with another no brainer for one of you wonderful wizards, Ive been playing around with awk, and havent quite got this figured out yet. So without further delay, here is the problem I am trying to solve.

I have two files

file1 looks like this ( actual file has hundreds of lines w random words )

```
somewebsite
someotherwebsite
somestinking
blahblah
foobar
```

file2 looks something like this ( many tlds, a lot more )

```
.com.th
.co.uk
.com
.de
.ath.cx
```

Ok, I need each line in file1 to have each tld added from file2 on a new line....

To further elaborate, each line in file1 needs to be replicated so that it can have every tld from file2 added to every entry in file1.

Output should be something like this:

```
   somewebsite.com.th
   somewebsite.co.uk
   somewebsite.com
   somewebsite.de
   somewebsite.ath.cx
   someotherwebsite.com.th
   someotherwebsite.co.uk
   someotherwebsite.com
   someotherwebsite.de
   someotherwebsite.ath.cx
   somestinking.com.th
   somestinking.co.uk
   somestinking.com
   somestinking.de
   somestinking.ath.cx
   blahblah.com.th
   blahblah.co.uk
   blahblah.com
   blahblah.de
   blahblah.ath.cx
   foobar.com.th
   foobar.co.uk
   foobar.com
   foobar.de
   foobar.ath.cx
```

I hope that makes sense to somebody, Im trying to figure out how to do it, its certainly amusing all the ways I have failed.

Thank you in advance. Im sure I am not the only person who has tried this now, in the past, or in the future, so a solution will certainly help the next person attempting to do this.

Comment: Instead of insolent praises you should: 1.) add your code what do you tried, or 2.) just say: _im lazy, so make for me a script_.

Comment: Im genuinely asking for help. Those type of remarks are unnecessary.

Comment: You should read the [help]. Here we helping developers overcome problems with their work. You didn't posted anything what could be called as "work", thus you didn't even tried to solve the problem. So, you just asking for a free developer work and missed the point of the site.

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a) print $1 i}' file2 file1
somewebsite.co.uk
somewebsite.de
somewebsite.com
somewebsite.ath.cx
somewebsite.com.th
...
```

The order the tlds come out is random due to the nature of `in` operator.

Or just use `join` (and `tr`):

```
$ join  -j 2 file1 file2 | tr -d ' '
somewebsite.com.th
somewebsite.co.uk
somewebsite.com
somewebsite.de
...
```

Comment: +++ for the `join`. Anyway - you can just `join  -j 2 -t '' file1 file2` e.g specify the `-t` - separator to empty string.

Comment: @jm666 I did try it actually but i got pairs of items on top of eachother and the pairs separated by empty lines. Did it work for you? (join (GNU coreutils) 8.21)

Comment: Arghhh ;( - Then the BSD version of `join` is different from GNU one. Me using `OS X` so in the BSD it works, but you're right - in the GNU join does not.

Comment: @jm666 Works on `join (GNU coreutils) 8.22`

Comment: @123 But not on `join (GNU coreutils) 8.23` again. Wut?

Comment: Locale related? What are you on? (no pun :) I'm on en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @JamesBrown Dunno maybe, `en_GB.UTF-8`

Comment: I think by trying to join on a non-existent field you're in deepest, darkest undefined behavior territory so YMMV. At least I can't find anything in [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) or any `join` man page that says what that should do. `+1` for the awk though.

Comment: `join -j999` for generating cross product is a very common technique...

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$head file?
==> file1 <==
somewebsite
someotherwebsite
somestinking
blahblah
foobar

==> file2 <==
.com.th
.co.uk
.com
.de
.ath.cx
$while read a; do while read b; do echo "$a$b"; done < file2; done < file1
somewebsite.com.th
somewebsite.co.uk
somewebsite.com
somewebsite.de
somewebsite.ath.cx
someotherwebsite.com.th
someotherwebsite.co.uk
.....
.....
```

Comment: That did exactly what I was hoping it would, thank you for answering the question to my problem with a functional and elegant answer, thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: @derpderpalert - Welcome :)

Comment: Make sure to read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some of the reasons not to do this (e.g. it's extremely inefficient and will produce unexpected/incorrect output given some input).

Comment: oh my, I wonder what will occur if some of my entries look like  some-website-with-dashed.com or some_other_website.sucks

Comment: @derpderpalert - Try with above command and share the result if you are facing any issue/wrong output.