# Using join for cartesian product

Tags: bash, shell, unix, gnu-coreutils

In the comments of [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819203/4162356) started a discussion related to using GNU coreutils' `join` for creating cartesian product of two files. A fellow user suggested that:

```
$ join -j 2 -t '' file1 file2
```

produces cartesian product of `file1` and `file2`:

```
$ cat file1
1
2
$ cat file2
a
b
```

Expected output:

```
$ join -j 2 -t '' file1 file2
1a
1b
2a
2b
```

Well, I'm getting:

```
$ join -t '' -j 2 file1 file2

1
a

1
b

2
a

2
b
```

I've tested in 2 Debian Jessies (`join` (GNU coreutils) 8.23) and a Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (`join` (GNU coreutils) 8.21) with C and en_US.utf8 locales (all systems installed and administered by different parties). Reportedly `join` behaves as expected in OS X and a system with `join` (GNU coreutils) 8.22.

Has anyone ran into this before? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tried it and got your desired output :
 `bash-3.00$ join -j 2 -t "" t1 t2  
1a  
1b  
2a  
2b`  
also tried it at tcsh and csh and it worked there as well. check maybe some part of your unix karnel is messed up.

Comment: @user2141046 You're still on bash 3? Please update your system and `join` version (`join --version`)?

Comment: join (GNU coreutils) 8.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need use as delimiter '\0'

```
join -t '\0' -j 2 file1 file2
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, good job! Any idea why `\0` needed in my systems?

Comment: i'm not sure, but -t need specify char as argument,null character is  '\0'

Comment: Not sure: `man join`: - - _or use "join -t ''" if 'sort' has no options_ - -